# Geting all prime numbers from the fibonacci sequence in a range of <1000

Tags: prime-numbers

So my attempt was:

```
PrimePi[Fibonacci[Range[1, 999]]]
```

But that doesnt compile into anything. no result no error.

i hope one of you got an idea.

Comment: Try PrimeQ, which gives True or False for whether each element is a prime.

Comment: _Compile_ is the wrong word here, I think you mean _evaluate_. Try this: `Select[Fibonacci@Range@999, PrimeQ]`

Comment: @flinty thanks this worked out super well!

Comment: Do you want the first 1000 Fibonacci numbers or do you want the Fibonacci numbers with values <1000?  Interestingly on my machine (3GHz iMAC w/ 10 Core) and MMA 12.1.1) PrimePi[Fibonacci[999]] immediately returns 0.